# How to scroll up textview automatically when new text entered like in chat apps?

Tags: ios, scroll, uitextview

[image]I am making a chat application , i want to do that when text is send using button then textview will scroll up and show the text. now what is happening that i have to scroll the view not automatic when send the chat.
Thanks

```
-(void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView 
{ 
    if(_tvChat.text.length > 0 ) 
    { 
        NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 2);     
        [_tvChat scrollRangeToVisible:bottom]; 
    } 
}
```

this is happenning 
and what i want that like this when click on send button and text will show up[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting contentOffset? Moreover after sending the message you should empty the UITextView object.

Comment: -(void)scrollTextViewToBottom:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if(_tvChat.text.length > 0 )
    {
        NSRange bottom = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length -1, 2);
        [_tvChat scrollRangeToVisible:bottom];
    }
    
} i have done this

Comment: If you use a tableview in chat app then it will be much better than UITextView & scrolling problem will get resolve easily using tableview delegate.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS If u have any code for textview automatic scroll then please send....

Comment: Aayush, I don't have any code for textview but Yes I have a sample for tableview. https://github.com/sunillohar/quickblox/tree/master/sample-chat

Download this code & views folder find class ChatMessageTableViewCell. Add this in your project & perform setting as you find in downloaded code. it will work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

YOu have to implement a delegate method. The code below says. If you hit return. Scroll to bottom of the textView

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {
        textView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, textView.contentSize.height);
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0, self.scrollView.contentSize.height - self.scrollView.bounds.size.height);
[self.scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:YES];
```